# Return blank data if the column is empty in SQL

Tags: sql

I have run the following query which returns 36 rows of data

```
SELECT 
    A.OBJECTIVE, SUM(A.T_VALUE)
FROM 
    DB2ADM2.TFINTR10 A
WHERE 
    (A."YEAR" =10)
    AND (A.OBJECTIVE BETWEEN 'WAAAA' AND 'WZZZZ')
GROUP BY 
    A.OBJECTIVE


When I merge with another table and add the Narration field (OB_Narr5) the rows of data are reduced as the Ob_Narr5 does not exist for every Objective, see sql.

    SELECT A.OBJECTIVE, SUM ( A.T_VALUE ), B.OB_NARR5
    FROM DB2ADM2.TFINTR10 A INNER JOIN DB2ADM2.TFINOBJP B ON B.OB_12345 = A.
         OBJECTIVE
    WHERE (A."YEAR" =10)
    AND A.OBJECTIVE BETWEEN 'WAAAA' AND 'WZZZZ'
    GROUP BY A.OBJECTIVE, B.OB_NARR5

The rows returned are now only 4.

How can I return all the rows including the blank fields and / or return just the rows with the blank fields?
```

Thanks for replies, Left and Full Outer Join both work.

```
How do I replace the <NULL> with a blank instead please?

WAAAA   -173597.12  <NULL>
WABAA   222717.76   GENERAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Full Outer Join** for preserving values from both the tables
or **Left Outer Join** for any particular table

Answer (score 5):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` which doesnt drop entries of the left table containing empty columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.OBJECTIVE
    ,SUM(A.T_VALUE)
    ,B.OB_NARR5
from DB2ADM2.TFINTR10 A
left join DB2ADM2.TFINOBJP B on B.OB_12345 = A.OBJECTIVE
where A."YEAR" = 10
    and A.OBJECTIVE between 'WAAAA' and 'WZZZZ'
group by A.OBJECTIVE
    ,B.OB_NARR5
```